# Setting AndroidSlidingUpPanel anchor to a specific view

Tags: java, android

I'm using https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel which is great so far.

Currently, I use `setAnchorPoint` for setting an anchor. 
I would like to set an anchor to a specific view, is it possible ?

Thanks !

Comment: https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @NileshRathod How is that helping ?

Answer (score 0):

setAnchorPoint requires a float between 0 and 1 that is the percentage:

```
0.3 = 30% of the screen.
```

So you have to find the position of the view that you would like to set as anchor.
Using getLocationOnScreen()

```
int[] location = new int[2];
myView.getLocationOnScreen(location);
int y = location[1];
```

And the convert the y to a float value between 0 and 1.